# What's the name of Kuchiki Rukia's real parents?

Tags: bleach

In Bleach, Kuchiki Rukia is said to be nurtured by the Kuchiki family. Can anyone tell me the names of her real parent?

Comment: i don't think it's stated, the [wikia's](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Rukia) earliest point in Rukia's history is her and Hisana arriving in Rukon 150 ago which would mean they died together, since it doesn't state that they came with their parents (given Hisana was finding it hard to care for Rukia and live in Rukon) chnaces are their parents died long before and during the Soul Society Arc Horiuchi Hironari says it's rare to be reunited with family members who died earlier which tends to generate family groups by those who die later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Memor-X said

> i don't think it's stated, the [wikia's](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Rukia) earliest point in Rukia's history is her and Hisana arriving in Rukon 150 ago which would mean they died together, since it doesn't state that they came with their parents (given Hisana was finding it hard to care for Rukia and live in Rukon) chnaces are their parents died long before and during the Soul Society Arc Horiuchi Hironari says it's rare to be reunited with family members who died earlier which tends to generate family groups by those who die later

Rukia being an orphan is an integral point of her (and Renji's) back story, fitting into the general desperation and poverty of the Rukon district.

As such, her parents have never been identified and most likely never will.